# Manipulate shows an empty plot

Tags: plotting, manipulate

My `Manipulate` expression

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[100[x]^2/(T^4 (Exp[x/T] + 1)), {x, 0, 30}], 
  {T, 1, 4}]
```

shows an empty plot. How can I fix it?

Comment: `100[x]^2` is not proper syntax.  Probably want `100(x)^2`.  Brackets `[]` denote function calls

Comment: Actually no bracketing around `x` is needed: `100 x^2/(T^4 (Exp[x/T] + 1))` works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way much clearer

```
f[x_, t_] := (100*x^2)/(t^(4) *(Exp[x/t] + 1))


Manipulate[Plot[
f[x, t], {x, 0, 30}, Axes -> {True, True}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 50}}], {t, 1, 4}]
```

Result

[image]